# How to prevent getting duplicate hrefs using getAttribute Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I keep getting same links from the site which I'm testing.

**This is my code**
        "

```
List<WebElement> activeLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

        //2.Iterate LinksList: Exclude all the links/images - doesn't have any href attribute and exclude images starting with javascript.
        boolean breakIt = true;
        for(WebElement link:AllTheLinkList) 
        {
            breakIt = true;
            try
            {
                //System.out.println((link.getAttribute("href")));
                if(link.getAttribute("href") != null && !link.getAttribute("href").contains("javascript") && link.getAttribute("href").contains("pharmacy")) //&& !link.getAttribute("href").contains("pharmacy/main#"))
                {
                    activeLinks.add(link);          
                }   
            }
            catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
            {
                breakIt = false;
            }
            if (breakIt) 
            {
                continue;
            }
        }       

        //Get total amount of Other links
        log.info("Other Links ---> " + (AllTheLinkList.size()-activeLinks.size()));
         //Get total amount of links in the page
        log.info("Size of active links and images in pharmacy ---> "+ activeLinks.size());

        for(int j=0; j<activeLinks.size(); j++) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();

            connection.setConnectTimeout(4000);
            connection.connect();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage(); //Ok
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            connection.disconnect();
            //System.out.println((j+1) +"/" + activeLinks.size() + " " + activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href") + "---> status:" + response + " ----> code:" + code);
            log.info((j+1) +"/" + activeLinks.size() + " " + activeLinks.get(j).getAttribute("href") + "---> status:" + response + " ----> code:" + code);  
        }
```

And this is my output: 
[I'm getting same links again and again. it's like they are repeating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CxBg.png)

Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Can you point out where you are getting duplicate hrefs ?

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML and console output

Comment: @Code_10 I think it's here 
                if(link.getAttribute("href") != null && !link.getAttribute("href").contains("javascript") && link.getAttribute("href").contains("pharmacy"))

Comment: @Code_10 check the screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CxBg.png

Comment: Show the HTML of several links

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the list items to a set because set does not allow duplicates. 
For example:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    Set<WebElement> hrefs = new HashSet<WebElement>(anchors);
    Iterator<WebElement> i = hrefs.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        WebElement anchor = i.next();
        if(anchor.getAttribute("href").contains(href)) {
            anchor.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not helping @M06494h

Comment: You can try clearing cache on your browser using 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Can you please give me a detailed explanation. May be i'm doing something not correct.

Comment: When I copied to set it gave me an error with:
Error:(121, 83) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: variable activeLinks of type java.util.Set<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>